# jQuery ajax method return 404, but 200 is returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm debugging my code in Opera.

This is code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://super-site.com/actions.x",
    data: "act=super&url=puper",
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
}).error(function(data, textStatus, errorThrown){    
    alert(data.status);
});
```

I receive alert with text "404", **but** in Opera Network Inspector request returns 200, with needed data!

response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/0.7.67
Date: Thu, 06 Jun 2013 01:07:43 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=WINDOWS-1251
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze14
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 26
```

What has happend? (this is cross site scripting)

Comment: Looks like  a cross domain request

Comment: Same Origin Policy...is your site also hosted on super-site.com

Comment: yes its an cross domain request

Comment: Add a `crossDomain : true` just in case

Comment: And musnt the type be `jsonp`?

Comment: You are unable to do a cros domain with post ajax... Your going to have to use either getjson, or curl there are more options but those 2 are your best bet. if you want i can elaborate a little

Comment: @NetaMeta : its possible to `POST` to cross domain urls. Please look at this post.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript